# Якорь при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

При обновлении страницы якорь остается в URL пути. Что с этим делать?

Comment: Пусть остаётся, так и должно быть, зачем с этим что-то делать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно, чтобы после якорь сделал свое дело один раз, когда вы использовали якорную ссылку, а после его не стало, то можете просто удалить якорь из ссылки:

```
if(location.hash) history.replaceState({}, document.title, location.href.split('#')[0]);
```

После этого ссылка в адресной строке сменится на ссылку без якоря и последующее обновление странице не "стриггерит" якорь

Answer (score 0):

За событие смены якоря отвечает событие `hashchange` у `window`.
Методом замены состояния можно выключить якорь из URL:

```
history.replaceState(null,"", e.oldURL);
```

```js
onhashchange = e => {
  history.replaceState(null,"", e.oldURL);
}
```

```css
div { height: 500vh; }
```

```html
<a id="contents"><h2>Contents</h2></a>
<a href="#test1">#test1</a><br/>
<a href="#test2">#test2</a>
<div></div>
<a id="test1"><h2>Test1</h2></a>
<a href="#contents">#contents</a><br/>
<a href="#test2">#test2</a>
<div></div>
<a id="test2"><h2>Test2</h2></a>
<a href="#contents">#contents</a><br/>
<a href="#test1">#test1</a>
<div></div>
```